# "Filtrar" resultados en base a parametro enviado por url en PHP

Tags: php, array

Me encuentro haciendo un trabajo práctico para la facultad, en el que debo armar una página web de una temática dada, haciendo la navegación por modelo de templates.

La página principal contiene su barra de navegación en 3 secciones, haciendo el `isset` de lo que llega por get y haciendo el `include` de cada template funciona perfecto.

El problema llega cuando estoy dentro de la segunda sección, que en este caso se llama "instrumentos" y tengo una sub barra de navegación. En esa sección que tiene como botones los tipos: "viento", "cuerdas", "percusión"... En este template, en principio se deben mostrar todos los instrumentos, trayéndolos desde un array (esto ya está hecho, se muestran perfectamente), pero al hacer click en alguno de los botones, solo deben aparecer los que correspondan. Si se hace click en viento, solo debera mostrar los de viento y así, pero esto debe ocurrir sin incluir un nuevo template.

Entiendo que debo pasar un nuevo parámetro por get, pero no logro hacer que se muestren los instrumentos del tipo solicitado.

El array es asi:

```
$instrumentos = array(
    array(
          'nombre' => 'Bajo Barriltono',
          'descripcion' => 'Fue construido por Carlos Iraldi como una parodia del contrabajo. La caja armónica es un gran barril sobre el que va adosada la tastiera con las cuerdas. Para ejecutar este instrumento el músico debe introducirse dentro del barril sacando los brazos por la parte superior. Posee además 5 ruedas en la parte inferior que permiten al ejecutante ir caminando mientras toca el instrumento. Su intérprete es Jorge Maronna y se lo puede ver en la obra "San Ictícola de los peces" del espectáculo Unen canto con humor.',
          'tipo' => 'Cuerdas',
          'foto' =>'bajo_barriltono.jpg'
    ),
```

Lo que se envía por url debería quedar algo como esto, ¿verdad?

```
<li><a href="index.php?cat=instr&tipo=cuerda">Cuerda</a></li>
```

¿Qué evaluación debería hacer para traer solo los de cada tipo?

No se permite uso de js, jquery, en fin, nada que no sea PHP.
La vista de la seccion es la siguente:

```
<section id="instrumentos">
    <div>
        <h2>Instrumentos</h2>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php?cat=instr&tipo=cuerda">Cuerda</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?cat=instr&tipo=viento">Viento</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?cat=instr&tipo=percu">Percusión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
<div class="grilla_instrumentos">
<?php
    foreach($instrumentos as $item => $instru){
    echo '<div class="instrumento">';
    echo '<h3>'.$instru['nombre'].'</h3>';
    echo '<img src="recursos/img/'.$instru['foto'].'"/>';
    echo '<p><a href="index.php?cat=ver&amp;i='.$item.'">VER MAS</a></p>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
?>

</div>                  
</section>
```

Comment: Vaya, sin Ajax y sin recargar la pagina si lo veo bastante complicado.

Comment: Obligatoriamente tienes que recargar la web ya que php no permite canbiar la UI sin refrescar el navegador. O puedes usar jQuery

Comment: No tengo permitido usar jquery @FrankLeal
Decis que deberia armar un template por cada parametro que llega? Tecnicamente el tipo no quiere eso, pero no sabria como hacerlo sino

Comment: Puedes crear un formulario, en la página donde tienes el tipo de sección y que al hacer un submit captures el valor  que quieres filtrar.  Aplicas  el filtro al array, para que te muestres el contenido que deseas  y lo que estas haciendo con el submit  es recargando la misma página. Si tienes el código de la vista seria bueno que lo colocaras

Comment: @YoelRodriguez edite la publicacion con el contenido de la vista

Comment: Una posible solución,  es que coloques un **if elseif**, dentro del foreach. Para que cuando tu selecciones cualquiera de los tres enlaces que tienes captures el valor por get. Ese valor se lo pases el **if elseif**  y el te mostraría  de acuerdo a lo que tu pases. Esto seria basado en que el **href** se lo haces a la misma página. Si no me logre explicar te puedo dejar un ejemplo

Comment: Puede ser con if o con case pero lo mejor es q armes todos desde el controlador y si necesitas cambiar algo en la bista tienes q recargar la pagina entera para q se actualize por que php es para servidor no para cliente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podes hacer es ver si esta seteada la variable tipo, usando el $_REQUEST (el $_GET tambien funciona), en caso de no estar seteado se imprime todo. Pero si esta seteado solo imprime lo que esta especificado. Ojo, veo que te falta un boton que diga volver o algo asi una vez que seleccionas una subcategoria.

```
<section id="instrumentos">
    <div>
        <h2>Instrumentos</h2>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php?cat=instr&tipo=cuerda">Cuerda</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?cat=instr&tipo=viento">Viento</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?cat=instr&tipo=percu">Percusión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
<div class="grilla_instrumentos">
<?php
    foreach($instrumentos as $item => $instru){
       $mostrar = true;
       if(isset($_REQUEST["tipo"])){
         if ($_REQUEST["tipo"] != $instru["tipo"]){
           $mostrar = false;
         }
       }
       if ($mostrar == true){
           echo '<div class="instrumento">';
           echo '<h3>'.$instru['nombre'].'</h3>';
           echo '<img src="recursos/img/'.$instru['foto'].'"/>';
           echo '<p><a href="index.php?cat=ver&amp;i='.$item.'">VER MAS</a></p>';
           echo '</div>';
       }
    }
?>

</div>                  
</section>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo! Me funciono muy bien con algunos pequeños cambios!